# How to generate Tailwind javascript for static html page

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I created a static html page with Tailwind components.

I have a package.json file and a tailwind.config.js file, and build it with:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./input.css -o ./output.css --watch
```

Now, how do I also generate the required javascript? I'm using a Tailwind navigation component that requires js for mobile. How can I generate that JS without using NextJS or React?

Comment: Tailwind only generates CSS. For any JavaScript functionality, you'd need to write it yourself.